# Link against framework depending on macro

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, frameworks, ios8

I defined a preprocessor macro like:

```
#define ENABLE_SPECIAL_FEATURES 1
```

I want to have a possibility to link against a framework. So if the macro is set to "1", the framework should be linked against. If set it to "0", it shouldn´t

Is that possible?

Comment: Why? Why would you not just have 2 targets, one with and one without?

Comment: How exactly would I do that with two targets?

Comment: I think actually you would need to weak link the framework and then only use it if the preprocessor macro is defined, and only one of the targets would have it defined...

Comment: Already got it...I implemented two targets...thanks for the tip...